# Python 2.7: While converting a list to dict, a key-value pair is missing from the dict. Why?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have a list that I am trying to convert into a dictionary, but for some reason one of the expected key-value pairs is missing from the resultant dictionary and I can't figure out why.

```
le_list = ['Social security and child support:', 'sscsa-glasgow@justice.gov.uk', 'Enquiries:', 'enquiries-cicap@hmcts.gsi.gov.uk', 'Social security and child support:', '0300 790 6234', 'Social security and child support fax:', '01264 347 981']
for i in le_list:
    k = le_list[0::2]
    v = le_list[1::2]

le_dict = dict(zip(k, v))
print(le_dict)

{'Enquiries:': 'enquiries-cicap@hmcts.gsi.gov.uk', 'Social security and child support fax:': '01264 347 981', 'Social security and child support:': '0300 790 6234'}
```

When I do a simple test with another list, it works fine:

```
le_list = ['A:', '1', 'B:', '2', 'C', '3', 'D', '4']
for i in le_list:
   k = le_list[0::2]
   v = le_list[1::2]

le_dict = dict(zip(k, v))
print(le_dict)

{'C': '3', 'A:': '1', 'D': '4', 'B:': '2'}
```

What is causing `[u'Social security and child support:', u'sscsa-glasgow@justice.gov.uk']` not to be included as a dict key-value pair?

Comment: You can't have multiple keys which are the same thing. See your first and third key.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I was looking at `Social security and child support:` and thinking "it's exactly the same, why would it work with one and not the other?". Thanks - a lesson learned!

Comment: yes @coldspeed is correct! its value is updated and thus its giving you the latest value!